# nhow to find latest day of entry into a row?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet to track daily activity, were in I used to update whether I have completed thta activity in a particular day. Other days remained blank, if activity not done. Suppose I have in one row entries "Y" or blank as per dates in each column. How do I find latest day of entry using a formula?

e.g. --

-----------------------1Jan----2jan----3jan-----31Jan......Latest entry day?

Taken Medicine?---Y-----------------Y---------------..... ???? (here.. '3' for 3rd jan)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula that will find the last cell with text in the desired row:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,MATCH("ZZZ",2:2))
```

The match finds the last cell in the row that has text and returns the corresponding value in row 1.  This only works if the dates in row 1 are true dates and not text that look like dates.

If the dates are text the you will need to use this formula:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,MATCH("ZZZ",$A2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMN()-1)))
```

[image]